# How is a Civilization's literacy calculated?

Tags: civilization-5

Literacy is one of the demographics in Civilization 5.  How is it calculated? How do you compare two civilizations via this statistic? Are you able to tell how advanced a civ is compared to you by comparing your relative Literacy ratings?

Comment: I believe it's related to science.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the percentage of the total technologies you've researched, as long as you have writing, otherwise it's always 0.  Note that what follows is not my research, I found this on the [CivFanatics forums](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=395961):

From Assets/UI/InGame/Popups/Demographics.lua:

```
function GetLiteracyValue( iPlayer )

    local pTeamTechs = Teams[ Players[ iPlayer ]:GetTeam() ]:GetTeamTechs();

    local iWriting = GameInfoTypes[ "TECH_WRITING" ];
    if( iWriting ~= nil and 
        not pTeamTechs:HasTech( iWriting ) ) then
        return 0;
    end

    local iCount = 0;
    for row in GameInfo.Technologies() do
        if( pTeamTechs:HasTech( row.ID ) ) then
            iCount = iCount + 1;
        end
    end

    return 100 * iCount / #GameInfo.Technologies;
end
```

Since "Future Tech" never gets fully researched, you can never reach 100% literacy.